# How can I recover disk space after having used buildx?

Tags: docker, buildx

I have Docker 24.0.4 on Centos 7. I have tried to generate some big multiplatform images and now I have 10 GB of wasted space that I don't know how to reclaim.

Following [this tutorial](https://dev.to/aws-builders/using-docker-buildx-to-create-cross-platform-docker-images-for-seamless-compatibility-4k8b) I have executed

```
docker buildx create --use --name buildx_instance
```

then I built some images (`docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 ...`) and finally I tried to clean everything with:

```
docker buildx stop buildx_instance
docker buildx rm buildx_instance
docker buildx prune
docker system prune
```

But I noticed that 10 GB are still missing, so I examined Docker's folders with `ncdu` and I found some big subfolders of `docker/vfs/dir` that clearly contain files of the images I have just built with `buildx`.

The tutorial says that images created with `buildx`

> won't be visible under `docker images` and these images will
> be in buildx cache only

so how can I delete them?  I don't want to use a brute force approach (stop/delete/reinstall everything). And how can I associate each subfolder of `docker/vfs/dir` to the right image?

Note also that I don't know why my Docker is using `vfs` instead of `overlay2`; I discovered it searching for the wasted space.  The file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` contains only

```json
{
  "data-root": "/docker"
}
```

because `/var` is in a very small filesystem.

I have another Centos 7 machine with Docker 23.0.6 without `/etc/docker/daemon.json`: it has  the `overlay2` folder instead of `vfs`.  I used `buildx` on this machine too, in the same way, and I don't see wasted space.  Why?  What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already tried `docker system prune`, now I have tried also `docker system prune -a` and it solved my problem.

It deleted all not-running images (expected and unwanted but acceptable) and some "**build cache objects**" then said:

```
Total reclaimed space: 4.332GB
```

but the difference reported by `df -h` is 13 GB and the folders that I wanted to remove are gone.

Answer (score 1):

Docker falls back to `vfs` when the backing filesystem does not support one of the other graph drivers. This is commonly seen with Docker in Docker installs since there are no other graph drivers that work on top of an overlay mount (overlay on top of overlay isn't supported). `vfs` is simply a full copy of the filesystem for every layer, which uses a lot of space and is very slow (every new container is also a full copy).

For overlay support, you need to ensure the docker root is on a supported backing filesystem. Documentation for that is at:

https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/#supported-backing-filesystems

There are two places images can be cached. In the builder itself, and in the local docker image cache if you didn't push to a registry. The builder will be pruned with `docker buildx prune`. The local image cache can be pruned with `docker image prune` which would only delete untagged images. To include tagged images, `docker image prune -a` will also delete any unused images. To be more selective, you can delete the individual images you created with `docker image rm $image`.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I checked with the `xfs_info` command: both filesystems are `xfs` but the "bad" one has `ftype=0` instead of `ftype=1`.  This explains the difference between the two Docker instances, but the main problem remains how to recover the wasted space.

Comment: The space isn't technically wasted, each layer is reusable and needed if another build needs to reuse it from that point. vfs is just very inefficient in how it stores layers and you should change the host configuration to avoid it.

Comment: OK, but it was just an experiment with `buildx`: I don't need those multiplatform images anymore and want to delete them.  Is there any Docker command?  I suppose that manually deleting the subfolders of `docker/vfs/dir` that clearly contain the files of those images is not safe and I might miss some folders.

Comment: Does `docker buildx du` show the layers? If not, then the image is in the local image cache, not the builder. You would delete that with `docker image prune -a` which will also delete all tagged images on the host.

Comment: It's too late to try the two commands you suggested.  As reported in my own answer I solved with `docker system prune -a`.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: `docker system prune -a` maps to `docker image prune -a` when pruning images. And it will have no affect on `docker buildx du`.