# Reduce size of /var/lib/overlay2 (duplicated layers)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build, docker-overlay2

We are deploying a python based web application on a remote server. Recently the disk usage have been increasing rapidly, and i found out that /var/lib/docker/overlay2 folder is using 80GB.

Running `docker system df` shows:

```
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          23        23        6.272GB   2.774GB (44%)
Containers      23        23        428.1MB   0B (0%)
Local Volumes   15        13        2.238GB   76.51kB (0%)
Build Cache     79        0         6.687GB   6.687GB
```

Which is definitely not 80GB.

During further investigation i found that there is one folder which appears a lot of times in the /var/lib/docker/overlay2/**/diff, which is a folder within the web app container `/home/app/web`.

Running this command `du -ch --max-depth=0 /var/lib/docker/165536.165536/overlay2/**/diff/home/app/web` shows

```
68G total
```

which i think i quite high.

I am using this Dockerfile for the build:

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# copy project
COPY poetry.lock .
COPY pyproject.toml .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install poetry
RUN poetry export -f requirements.txt --without dev --output requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# TODO: det her bør være i faktisk prod
# RUN python -m pip_audit -r requirements.txt

RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt
RUN poetry version -s > version.txt

FROM python:3.11-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add libpq postgresql-client busybox-suid make
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# copy version.txt, må override version.txt fra local
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/version.txt .

#make entrypoint executable
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g'  $APP_HOME/entrypoint.prod.sh
RUN chmod +x  $APP_HOME/entrypoint.prod.sh

RUN mv ${APP_HOME}/entrypoint.web.prod.sh /
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g'  /entrypoint.web.prod.sh
RUN chmod +x  /entrypoint.web.prod.sh

#create backup directory
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/backup
RUN mkdir -p $APP_HOME/cissky/staticfiles
RUN mkdir -p $APP_HOME/cissky/mediafiles

# make documentation
# TODO: uncomment det her i faktisk produksjon
# RUN cd docs && make clean && make html && cd ..
RUN mkdir docs/html

# kjorer makemigrations i build i stedet
RUN python3 cissky/manage.py makemigrations --noinput

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app


# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

Im guessing im doing something wrong with the build. Could anyone please give me some pointers?

I know its not the logs which are the issue. Ive also tried `docker system prune --all --volumes`, but the size will not be reduced.

Comment: The `RUN chown` command is probably unnecessary and could significantly increase the image size.  Are you sure the difference is in the image size, and not the container-temporary filesystem?

Comment: @DavidMaze how would i confirm whether its the image size or writing to temporary filesystem? Ive run `docker container diff` and that shows some logs beeing written to a non-volume directory, but that is max 50MB.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot reproduce your problem, this is not a proven solution, just a little collection of hints.

1. As already noted in the comment above, the `RUN chown` command is not efficient because rewrites in a new layer all the files that it touches.
2. Also the `RUN apk update` is not efficient: it writes the apk cache on the filesystem, then you delete it writing a new layer but this deletion is only logical, not phisical.  The correct solution is

```
   RUN apk --no-cache add libpq postgresql-client busybox-suid make
```

without the subsequent `RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*`
(see [Alpine Dockerfile advantages of --no-cache vs. rm /var/cache/apk/*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49118579/685806)).

3. To find wasted space in images you can use https://github.com/wagoodman/dive, however the total size of your images is 6 GB, so your problem is elsewhere.
4. Perhaps `docker system prune` may help, or the more **drastic** `docker system prune -a`, but it will delete a lot of things so [read the doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) before using it!

   [In one case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77081958/685806) I solved a problem of wasted space with it; note that it reported "Total reclaimed space: 4.332GB" but the real gain was 13 GB.

Comment: Okay, i think i understand, thanks for the tips! However i dont understand why it grows so much over time? I feel like it mostly grows when im building a new image, but shouldnt it then delete old layers that it doesnt need? How can a 1,4GB image become 68GB in overlay2? I know there are some logs which are written to a non volume directory, but can that really become so large?